# nightwatch xpath selector not working

Tags: selenium, express, xpath, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm currently working on a node/express.js app for which I'm writing some e2e tests in nightwatch.  Today I hit a roadblock while trying to search for an element using the XPath locator strategy. Basically I can search for elements using any of the following:

```
//div[@data-pino-name='userIdSection']
//input[@name="password"]
//input[@name="username"]
//button[@data-pino-name="submit"]
//a[@data-pino-name="cancel"]
```

By the way, all of the selectors above work fine using the chrome tools.

However, using the following:

```
//pre[@data-pino-name="requiredErrorMessage"]
```

doesn't work at all.  I'm surprised since I expected the `<pre>` tag to be treated the same as any other html tag.  However, the test returns a "element was not found" for all elements with the pre tag.

Anyone guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the HTML or XML from which you wish to select such `pre` elements.

Comment: I can't post the entire document due to privacy reasons but the structure of the document is more or less like this:

 `<div data-pino-name="root">
  <pre data-pino-name="blah">
  </pre>
  <div data-pino-name="foo">
  </div>
  <pre data-pino-name="bar">
  </pre>
 </div>`

any xpath that starts with //div[@element-name="value"] works just fine.  anything that starts with //pre doesn't.

Comment: Sanitize the data and produce a [mcve] if you'd like help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach in writing XPath based on your scenario

```
//div[@data-pino-name='userIdSection']/pre
//div[@data-pino-name='userIdSection']/pre[@data-pino-name="requiredErrorMessage"]
```

Comment: Edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: @shaoaib akhtar - thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately this didn't work in nightwatchjs.  I'm thinking there's an issue with the way nightwatch's implementation.  I'm going to file an issue report once I can get a jsfiddle running.